# Using Task<T> and actions for simple threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

My question is regarding a rather inelegant solution to a problem that I came up with a while ago.

I was making a Winform Application to access active directory among other things and needed to thread my application to stop my UI from freezing.

Although I have little knowledge of actual threading (I kept hitting cross-thread access issues), I've built a little function that allowed me to pass an object, act on it in a separate thread and then once it returned to the UI CurrentContext I could act on it again to update the view.

TL;DR

The below function sends a Generic Item to a separate thread, then once acted upon, returns the item and acts on it again.

```
public static void doThreadedQuery<T>(Func<T> processQuery, Action<T> onComplete)
{
    TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task<T> doQuery = new Task<T>(processQuery);
    doQuery.ContinueWith((results) => { if (onComplete != null) onComplete(results.Result); }, scheduler);
    doQuery.Start();
}
```

An example usage for something similar is pass an `activeDirectory` `SearchResultCollection`, parse through it and generate a TreeView/Grid. Then return the populated grid and UI updated without freezing.

Now I have done variants with a progress function/cancellation token etc, but I suppose my question is: on a base level, is there some horrible inefficiency or simple equivalent I am unaware of (aside from the Background Worker I am not overly fond of)?

I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't [usually](https://web.archive.org/web/20160724072141/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx) use `Task` constructor directly, use `Task.Factory.StartNew` (or `Run`).

I also don't understand why you want to have a separate method for starting a task. It is completely superficial. It's just as useless as adding `Print` method that calls `Console.WriteLine` instead of using `Console.WriteLine` directly.

Normally, you just do this:

```
void SomeUICode ()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
        // This will run on thread pool
        return DoSomeExpensiveWork ();
    }).ContinueWith (result => {
        // This will run on UI thread
        UpdateUI (result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ());
}
```

It's basically  the same thing you wrote, but without abstracting it away `doThreadedQuery` **since there's nothing to abstract away here**.

However, if you don't mind using C# 5, you can simplify things with [`async`/`await`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh191443%28v=vs.140%29) operators:

```
async void SomeUICode ()
{
    var result = await Task.Factory.Run (() => {
        // This will run on thread pool
        return DoSomeExpensiveWork ();
    });

    // The rest of this method will be scheduled on UI thread:
    UpdateUI (result);
}
```

Note the `await` keyword that “splits” the method and schedules the rest of it as a continuation on current synchronization context (exactly the same thing you did manually).

I declared the function as `async void` but [you should only do this for event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415703/458193) (which have to be `void`). In all other cases, **declare the function as `async Task` so the calling code has a chance to wait for it to finish**:

```
async Task SomeUICode ()
{
    // ...
}
```

On a side note, `doThreadedQuery` is a rather unfortunate name because

- [.NET method names should be PascalCase, not camelCase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29);
- There's no “query” being performed, you're just scheduling an operation.

Comment: I think he was just indicating (by example name) a process running a structured Query language operation. But otherwise, nice examples!

Comment: @Spiked: Perhaps, but his method doesn't really “know” whether function passed to it does a LINQ query or something else, so it's still a bad naming decision.

Comment: `async void` [should be avoided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (in most cases)

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the remark, I amended my answer.

Comment: I forgot to change the example name when I took it from the project, it was doing an ActiveDirectory query and T was defined hence the name.